# Maximum depth of a tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, json, functional-programming, logic

My json structure is like a tree structure.
A non-leaf node has child in svalue attribute of structure JSON object.
A leaf node has the key "executionValueList"

In my JSON ,i have two nodes `P1`, `P2` at level 0.

- `P1` does not have any child. `P2` has two children `P21` and `P22`.
- `P21` does not have any child.
- `P22` has two child `P221` and `P222`.
- `P221` has no child and is leaf node.
- `P222` has two child `P2221` and `P2222`.
- `P2221` and `P2222` have no child and are leaf nodes.

So maximum no of nodes from root to any leaf node is 4 (`P2->P22->P222->P2221` or `P2->P22->P222->P2222`).

**Script:**

```js
var a = {};
var m = 0;
a[m] = 0;
var counter = {
  "executionList": ["exe1", "exe2"],
  "algoList": [{
    "name": "Algorithm1",
    "paramList": [{
      "name": "P1",
      "executionValueList": [{
        "name": "exe1",
        "value": "v1"
      }, {
        "name": "exe2",
        "value": "v2"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "P2",
      "svalue": [{
        "name": "P21",
        "executionValueList": [{
          "name": "exe1",
          "value": "v3"
        }, {
          "name": "exe2",
          "value": "v4"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "P22",
        "svalue": [{
          "name": "P221",
          "executionValueList": [{
            "name": "exe1",
            "value": "v5"
          }, {
            "name": "exe2",
            "value": "v6"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "P222",
          "svalue": [{
              "name": "P2221",
              "executionValueList": [{
                "name": "exe1",
                "value": "v5"
              }, {
                "name": "exe2",
                "value": "v6"
              }]
            }

          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Algorithm2",
    "paramList": [{
      "name": "P3",
      "executionValueList": [{
        "name": "exe1",
        "value": "v1"
      }, {
        "name": "exe2",
        "value": "v2"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "P4",
      "svalue": [{
        "name": "P21",
        "executionValueList": [{
          "name": "exe1",
          "value": "v3"
        }, {
          "name": "exe2",
          "value": "v4"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "P22",
        "svalue": [{
          "name": "P221",
          "executionValueList": [{
            "name": "exe1",
            "value": "v5"
          }, {
            "name": "exe2",
            "value": "v6"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "P222",
          "executionValueList": [{
              "name": "exe1",
              "value": "v7"
            }, {
              "name": "exe2",
              "value": "v8"
            }

          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

function parameterColumnCounter(counter) {
  var temp;
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(counter.algoList).length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(counter.algoList[i].paramList).length; j++) {
      temp = countInnerParameter(counter.algoList[i].paramList[j]);
    }
  }
  max = temp[0];
  for (n = 0; n < Object.keys(temp).length; n++) {
    if (max < temp[n]) {
      max = temp[n];
    }
  }
  return max
}

function countInnerParameter(parameter) {


  if ("svalue" in parameter) {

    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(parameter.svalue).length; j++) {
      a[m] = a[m] + 1;
      countInnerParameter(parameter.svalue[j]);
    }
  } else if ("executionValueList" in parameter) {
    a[m] = a[m] + 1;
    m = m + 1;
    a[m] = 0;

  }

  return a;

}



alert(parameterColumnCounter(counter));
```

I want to find maximum depth of the given tree structure.
But it is not giving the correct results.Counter is the Object which stores the entire structure.How to solve the given problem?

Comment: Maximum depth? `Infinity`. Consider `var json = {get example() { return json; }};`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 1 for the leaf node, as P2221 doesn't have 'svalue' parameter and hence is not being counted.